# Chi-Square test or T-test for the following two scenarios?

Tags: self-study

Suppose I want to test whether the new website generates more clickthrough rate through different types of data:

In the first scenario the data looks like the following:

[image]

> Is it correct to use Chi-Square test in this situation?

In the second scenario the data looks like the following:

[image]

> Is it correct to use T-test in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to our site! There are two datasets here and no clear purpose is stated. Data seem highly-rounded as one might expect to see in textbook problems. If my results from R are useful, fine. If not, please 'take the tour' of our site for pointers on asking good questions, revise your Question, show specific solutions you have tried, and consider including a `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first table I suppose you want to test
whether there is click rates for the two sites are
significantly different. This can be done in R as
shown below. (With such large sample sizes, I see
no reason for a continuity correction, so I omit
it with the parameter `cor=F` of `prop.test`.)

```
prop.test(c(1000,400), c(1500,1100), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(1000, 400) out of c(1500, 1100)
X-squared = 234.49, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2659193 0.3401413
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6666667 0.3636364
```

With observed click rates as different as $\hat p_A = 1000/1500 = 0.337$ and $\hat p_B = 400/1100 = 0.364,$
it is hardly astonishing that the null hypothesis of
equal click rates is rejected with a tiny P-value near $0.$

You give no clear idea in your question why you want
to do a statistical test for data in the second table or what null hypothesis you want to test.

Just scanning across the table it seems that B has
higher counts than A on Mon, Thurs, and maybe Fri.
A chi-squared test for homogeneity would test
whether the daily profile of counts differs significantly for the two sites.

```
TAB = rbind(c(250,300,200,320,410),
            c(400,350,200,400,500))
TAB
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]  250  300  200  320  410
 [2,]  400  350  200  400  500
 chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 15.33, df = 4, p-value = 0.004064
```

I have no idea why you are asking about a t test.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the null hypothesis for the second scenarios is H0: mean of clicks on Website A = Website B. I was thinking about T-test for two reasons: (1) I thought the number of clicks in the second scenario is regarded as continuous variable. (2) I have 5 samples for both websites, and I want the means of both sites to be compared. I am fairly new to statistics, can you resolve my confusion?

Comment: In cell (A,Mon) of the table, you have "250". I took that as 250 clicks, and wonder how many non-clicks there were.// If 250 is a count of something, you don't have 5 'samples' for A and B, you have 1480 of something for A & 1850 for B. // How can you 'take' click counts as a continuous variable? // For a paired t test with 5 paired diff's, you really should have 5 _normally_ dist'd observations. I don't see you have anything like that. // If _forced_ to put 5 diff's (such as $D_1 = 400-250)$ into the formula for a paired t test (totally unwarranted in my view), I get (meaningless) P-val 0.04.

Comment: Thank you so much again for taking the time to answer. In a hypothetical situation where the data in the second scenario are normally distributed and the variable "click" is changed to "dwell time" , will paired sample t-test be valid?

Comment: Possibly, depending on what the numbers actually represent. // For A/Monday is 250 average dwell time in sec:? If so, avg of how many users. Is 250 some sort of total? In what way are 250 for A/Mon and 400 for B/Mon related? comparable? // You can't just give a 'data table' and say, "Please analyze this." Have to know how data arose and what question they should help answer. // Where are you getting this stuff? Data are pretty obviously fake; otherwise hard to imagine why all numbers end in 0 or 00. And you don't seem to know what the purpose is.

Comment: Yes, the data and hypothesis are made-up because I am trying to figure out whether my understanding of the applications of t-test and chi-square test is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  The t-test is only needed when we have to estimate the variance separately from the mean.  In the first case, that isn't needed since the click is a binomial random variable and the variance is actually a function of the estimated mean.  Thus in the first test you can use a number of tests, you can use a test of proportions or a chi-square test.  With enough data, they should produce the same results.

The second scenario depends on your hypothesis.  If you want to determine if there is a difference on website visits between days, a chi-square test sounds good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for the second scenario, if what I want to find out if the clickthrough rates between website A and B is significant, should chi-square test be applied as well?

Comment: Btw, according to the hypothesis you mentioned(second scenario:difference on website visits between days), the independent variable would be "days" instead of "websites", is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, a chisquare should be fine.